# why is error is pop up ""TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'""

Tags: python

**Code**

```
import random

def deal_card():
  cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
  card = random.choice(cards)
  return card

def calculate_score(cards):
  if sum(cards) == 21 and len(cards) == 2:
     return 0
  if 11 in cards and sum(cards) > 21:
    cards.remove(11)
    cards.append(1)
 return sum(cards)

user_cards = []
computer_cards = []
is_game_over = False

for _ in range(2):
  user_cards.append(deal_card)
  computer_cards.append(deal_card)

user_score = calculate_score(user_cards)
computer_score = calculate_score(computer_cards)
print(f"   Your cards: {user_cards}, current score{user_score} ")
print(f"   computer first's cards: {computer_cards[0]} ")


if user_score == 0 or computer_score == 0 or user_score > 21:
  is_game_over = True
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 67, in <module>
   user_scores = calculate_score(user_cards)
  File "main.py", line 49, in calculate_score
    if sum(cards) == 21 and len(cards) == 2:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

Comment: `user_cards.append(deal_card)` appends the `deal_card` *function* to your list. It should be a function call: `deal_card()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually called the function. By doing:

```
user_cards.append(deal_card)
computer_cards.append(deal_card)
```

You are appending the "function" itself to the list. However, `sum` needs integers for calculating the sum. So it raises an error.

use `()` to call the function

```
user_cards.append(deal_card())
computer_cards.append(deal_card())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop where you are dealing cards, you don't call deal_card:

```py
for _ in range(2):
  user_cards.append(deal_card)#deal_card is a reference to the function, you need to call it for a result, deal_card()
  computer_cards.append(deal_card)#same here, use deal_card() instead
```

Instead of adding the return value of deal_card, you add the function itself to the list. `sum` tries to calculate the sum of the list, but that doesn't work as you can't add functions together.

Comment: That is better to show code that works instead of only the error code from the OP guy